# Is it possible to create COM add-in for excel using excel vba?

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I know that is possible to create an xla addin in VBA-Excel, however is not that secure, if the objective is to distribute to third partiy. I also know that is possible to create a COM add-in in Visual Studio, however I have already the code written in VBA and it would take me a while to accomplish the same in VB (VS).

Does anyone knows if is it possible to "translate" the VBA code for the add-in into VB code to create the COM add-in? or any other way to create the COM add-in for excel using the VBA code?

Thank you for the support

Comment: I believe the answer to your question is "No". Excel VBA and VB.Net are similar languages, but there are no automatic translation tools.

Comment: Unfortunately, since Office 2003 there has been no developer edition of Office (which used to allow you to create COM add-ins directly). If you have a copy of VB6, the code required would be extremely similar to VBA, but for .Net versions of VB some work would be needed. There may be commercial programs that will convert for you, though I don't know of any.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long answer. I'll just give you an example on how to develop a COM Add-in for excel and how to call any sub from Excel VBA. Below example is created on Visual Studio 2012.

First create a new "Office Excel Project" and name it VBCommAddin. Then from Project Menu Add New Class. Name the Class -> "ComAddinTest".

The class ComAddinTest.vb should have the following code -

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<ComVisible(True)> _
Public Interface ICommAddinUtils
    Sub SayHello()
End Interface

<ComVisible(True)> _

<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)> _
Public Class CommAddins
       Implements ICommAddinUtils  

    Public Sub SayHello() Implements ICommAddinUtils.SayHello
        MsgBox("Hello World!")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now in ThisAddin.vb add the following code -

```
Public utilities As ICommAddinUtils
Protected Overrides Function RequestComAddInAutomationService() As Object
    If utilities Is Nothing Then
        utilities = New CommAddinTest
    End If
    Return utilities
End Function
```

Open project properties -> Compile -> Check "Register for COM interop".

Now Build and run the program - MS Excel will be open. Go to VBA editor and add the Private sub given below -

```
Private Sub HelloWorld ()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
      Dim HelloWrld as COMAddin
      Dim AutomationObject as Object
      Set HelloWrld = Application.COMAddins("VBCommAddin")
      Set AutomationObject = HelloWrld.Object
      AutomationObject.SayHello
      Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox err.Description
End Sub
```

Now call the HelloWorld sub from any button click event of Macro event. Let me know if you need any further help on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

To create a COM you would require to wrap up you code in a object that could be in following format as dll, tlb, ocx, ActiveEx exe etc.

To wrap your code in above objects you would require an engine that provide mechanism to build such objects like VB6, or .NET.